# Asana developer

Tags: asana, asana-api, asana-connect

we use Asana as our internal project management platform.  We would like to use it to interact with our clients so they can see the progress of their projects - which is the same per year.  We created the Kanaban view and move the cards through each process.  We would like to show this to our clients, but have them only see their card.

Is there a way of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way that I'm aware of to have only certain tasks show up to certain people within a project - our access control is limited to the project level, so everyone who can see a project can see all tasks in a project.

One thing you might consider as a workaround is to multi-home the tasks into multiple projects (that is, add them into multiple projects). In this way you can limit membership to the second project to only the people in that set of clients, and have your original project as a master board with just your team in it.

You will have to keep these projects in sync, but this is possible in our API. Our [tasks/addProject](https://asana.com/developers/api-reference/tasks#projects) endpoint accepts both a project and a section (which is admittedly a bit unintuitive). If you maintain a mapping of each section, that is, "ID of Column A in the master board view maps to ID of Column B in the client board view", you can periodically iterate over all your tasks and re-insert each task in the client board view in the correct column based on where the task is in the master board view. (addProject is idempotent across requests, so re-insertions into a project are OK).

This is an interesting use case, thanks for sharing it! Hopefully this workaround will prove to be usable.